Why is killing even evil brahmins categorized as 'brahma hatya'?
The fact that in Hinduism 'brahma-hatya' is given special importance is discriminatory but we won't talk about that. What I am curious is why is the killing of evil brahmins - like Vritra by Indra and Ravana by Rama (I am talking about the Ramanathaswamy temple), also considered 'brahma-hatya' despite all the stuff that they had done? How is Ravana, the guy who had no self-control and wanted to covet another's wife, is considered a 'brahmin'? Isn't 'brahmin' supposed to 'not be by birth' but by guna and karma? Why does killing an evil brahmin lead to brahma-hatya 'dosa'?

There is no mention in the Valmiki Ramayana that Rama obtained brahma-hatya by killing Ravana. Nor is there any mention of Rama building any temple to expiate for the "sin of brahma-hatya". I do not even remember any mention that Ravana was a brahmin.

Then where does Ramanathaswamy temple come from?

@SuradoeUchiha we don't know, but it's not in Valmiki Ramayana. Also, obviously special importance would be given if a priest is killed and all or most Brahmanas of the time were priests and held the sacred word, killing them as per the faith would reasonably be a grevious sin. This is just common sense.

@estimator correct me, but no a Brahmin is based on birth, gunas, and karma. You have to have the blood of a Saptarishi in you.

There is no brahmahatya when a war initiated by brAhmaNa as per mahAbhArata-Adiparva-CLXLII  (arjuna in disguise of a brAhmaNa in this case):

Then those bulls among Brahmanas shaking their deer-skins and water-pots made of cocoanut-shells exclaimed, 'Fear not, we will fight
the foe!' Arjuna smilingly addressing those Brahmanas exclaiming thus,
said, 'Stand ye aside as spectators (of the fray) Showering hundreds
of arrows furnished with straight points even I shall check, like
snakes with mantras, all those angry monarchs.' Having said this, the
mighty Arjuna taking up the bow he had obtained as dower accompanied
by his brother Bhima stood immovable as a mountain. And beholding
those Kshatriyas who were ever furious in battle with Karna ahead, the
heroic brothers rushed fearlessly at them like two elephants rushing
against a hostile elephant. Then those monarchs eager for the fight
fiercely exclaimed, 'The slaughter in battle of one desiring to
fight is permitted.' And saying this, the monarchs suddenly rushed
against the Brahmanas.

padmapurANa-shrishtikhanda-chapter48 also says the same thing :

57. A man may kill in battle a brāhmaṇa desperado, desiring to kill, even though the desperado is a master of Vedanta. By (doing) that
(act) he does not become the killer of a brāhmaṇa.

shivapurANa-umAsamhita-chapter21 also says the same thing :

35. Even if a brahmin well-versed in Vedānta doctrine were to attack one violently with lethal weapons one can fight him in return. He will
not become guilty of brahminicide thereby.


Where do these injunctions come from? Mahabharata usually derive morals from Vedas and Dharmashastras. Do you know where in Vedas or Dharmashastras corresponding injunctions are written?

@SuradoeUchiha https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201281.html

Without hesitation one should strike an approaching desperado,—be he a preceptor, a child, or an aged man, or a highly learned Brāhmaṇa.—(350)
guruṃ vā bālavṛddhau vā brāhmaṇaṃ vā bahuśrutam |
ātatāyinamāyāntaṃ hanyādevāvicārayan || 350 ||

The commentary by Medhatithi is complicated, but looking down many other verses also give everyone the right to self-defense from a moral perspective.

This is the closest although not coresponding injunction.

EkAntika feel free to add this Manu verse and the others stated below.

@Haridasa thank you for the quote. It answered my question.

@SuradoeUchiha No problem bro!! :)

@Haridasa noted

A brahmana can only be killed in 2 cases 1.In battle 2.when He lethally attacks..
As we see in the case of Ashwatthama he was spared by Pandavas..
